# FancyBox in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, fancybox

I wonder how the fancy box in joomla. Because I can not just highlight the content you want to view page appears complete within fancybox. For example, I created an article listed within the fancybox, and when I click the link, the whole page appears. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Sorry for writing, english is not my native language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get what you say properly but after reading your question i come to know that you want to show article in fancy box & you have shown it but you can see whole page like menu & footer etc in modal popup. Am i right? so just add &tmpl=component in you link href. This will solve you problem.